# Scala compiler error on wildcard Array with val

Tags: scala

The following code fails when the constructor parameter is declared with val

Works:

```
class Poso(array : Array[_ <: Any])
object Test {
  new Poso(classOf[Retention].getEnumConstants())
}
```

Doesn't work:

```
class Poso(val array : Array[_ <: Any])
object Test {
  new Poso(classOf[Retention].getEnumConstants())
}
```

The compiler gives the error:

Error in Scala compiler: type mismatch; found :java.lang.Object required: array[java.lang.Object]

Without being able to give a line number.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error, neither in 2.9 nor in 2.10. Are you sure the error is caused by the val keyword?

Comment: Putting val in it breaks. If I have a member val and assign the constructor parameter to it then it works (that's what I'm doing). I'll update my question with the stack trace. What version of 2.9 are you using? I should also point out I'm using the scala maven plugin for my builds, so if its working for you (in "plain" scala) then it error could be in my stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Scala compiler (it dies on an exception). You should probably report it to Scala developers.

Using `AnyRef` instead of `Any` fixed it for me:

```
class Poso(val array : Array[_ <: AnyRef])
object Test {
  new Poso(classOf[java.lang.annotation.Retention].getEnumConstants())
}
```